How to Resolve "LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file" Error When Linking MuPDF C library with Node.js Addon?
I've built MuPDF
with the Dynamic Libr
ary(.dll) configuration and can see libmupdf.dll and libmupdf.exp files in  ....mupdf/platform/win32/x64/Release/
//binding.gyp :-
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "mupdf",

      "sources": ["src/mupdf/mupdf.cc"],

      "include_dirs": [
        "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")",
        "D:/vsprojects/Electron/ElectronPDF/mupdf/include"
      ],
      "libraries": [
        "D:/vsprojects/Electron/ElectronPDF/mupdf/platform/win32/x64/Release/libmupdf.lib"
      ],
      "link_settings": {
        "libraries": [
          "D:/vsprojects/Electron/ElectronPDF/mupdf/platform/win32/x64/Release/libmupdf.exp"
        ]
      },
      "defines": [
        "WIN32",
        "_WINDOWS"
      ],
      "msvs_settings": {
        "VCCLCompilerTool": {
          "RuntimeLibrary": 3  
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

Console output

Console output when running node-gyp
